# Problem using FormData and MultiFormData for send Files Images in Flutter with Dio

Tags: flutter, multipartform-data, dio

has anyone had this error using Dio and sending 'MultiPart FormData'?

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "target_value": listaDados[0],
  "number_installments": listaDados[1],
  "installments_frequency": listaDados[2],
  "modality": listaDados[3],
  "gross_billing": listaDados[4],
  "hectare_cost": listaDados[5],
  "files": [
    MultipartFile.fromFile("${listaDados[6]}",
        filename: "Foto_Identidade"),
    MultipartFile.fromFile("${listaDados[7]}",
        filename: "Foto_Imposto.jpg"),
    MultipartFile.fromFile("${listaDados[8]}",
        filename: "Selfie_Autorizacao.jpg"),
  ]
});
//dio.options.baseUrl = "${global.CONEXAO}";
dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor());
response = await dio.post("${global.CONEXAO}/credits",
    data: await formData,
    options: Options(headers: {
      'Authorization':
          'Bearer $token'
    }));
print(response.data);
```

When I send it like this, it gives status 200, sends all the data, but the files are [] ....

If I put await before MultiPart.fromfile, it gives error 500 and a list of [MapEntry (files []: Instance of 'MultipartFile'), MapEntry (files []: Instance of 'MultipartFile'), MapEntry (files [ ]: Instance of 'MultipartFile')] ...

- These photos are taken with the imagePicker and saved in a stream!
- There really is a file, I print the list beforehand and show the path and name of the file!
  Does anyone know what I can do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today，because the map get same key in the backend，so I can not get all the file finally，so I change the souce code as below:

```
  FormData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
_init();
encodeMap(
  map,
  (key, value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    if (value is MultipartFile) {
      files.add(MapEntry( value.filename, value)); //here is what I changed
    } else {
      fields.add(MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
    }
    return null;
  },
  encode: false,
);
```

}

when I change the source code and rebuild my app, everything works fine and I can use the filename as key.

If you dive into the `encodeMap` source code，you will find out that dio use a recursion to get all the key，value of the entries

but when come to MultipartFile in List ，the Entrance of this recursion is `urlEncode(data, '');` the path is empty，and finally we get something like `'$path$leftBracket${(sub[i] is Map || sub[i] is List) ? i : ''}$rightBracket');` , that turn out to be something like this

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('files[]', <FileStorage: 'image_picker677442617592930907_compressed1516097521471936562.jpg' ('application/octet-stream')>), ('files[]', <FileStorage: 'image_picker5187767999094318232_compressed6097930966098340000.jpg' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```